# Sequence of nested closed balls has not empty intersection, implies that a metric space is complete

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

I tried this exercise, and I do this:

Let $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a Cauchy sequence. 
Since is a Cauchy sequence, there exist a $x_0\in X$, and a $r_0$ such that $B_0=B(x_0, r_0)$ contains all points of the sequence. Clearly, we suppose that the sequence has infinite range.

Now, for $\epsilon=1$ exist $N \in  \mathbb{N}$ such that $d(x_n, x_m)<1$ if $n, m≥N$. Let $A_1=\{N \in \mathbb{N}: d(x_n, x_m)<1, \quad if \quad n, m≥N\}$. Then, $A_1 \not= \emptyset$. Hence, has minimum call it $N_1$. Therefore, as $x_{N_1} \in B_0$ and $B_0$ is open, there exist a $\epsilon_1>0$ such that $B(x_{N_1}, \epsilon_1) \subseteq B_0$. Let $r_1=\min\{\epsilon_1, 1\}$. So, $B_1=B(x_{N_1}, r_1) \subseteq B_0$.

For $\epsilon=\frac{r_1}{2}$, the set $A_2=\{N\in \mathbb{N}: d(x_n, x_m)<\frac{r_1}{2}\}$ is not empty and has minimum call it $N_2$. Note that $N_1≤N_2$ and that $x_{N_2}\in B_1$. Now, $B_1$ is open. There exist a $\epsilon_2>0$ with $B(x_{N_2}, \epsilon_2)\subseteq B_1$. Let $r_2=\min\{\epsilon_2, \frac{r_1}{2}\}$. So, $B_2=B(x_{N_2}, r_2)\subseteq B_1$. I continue in this way to construct a countable family of open balls such that $B_{k+1}\subseteq B_{k}$. Therefore, I considered the respective closed ball that I denoted as $C_k$. Note that $C_{k+1}\subseteq C_{k}$. By hypotesis, the intersection is not empty. So there exist a $x \in X$ such that it is in all closed balls 
In another hand, we notice that $\{x_{N_k}\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a subsequence that converge to $x$. But $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, so $x_n \rightarrow x$.

Comment: Looks good to me. .... The converse is also true, and, perhaps, easier.

Comment: This result can be applied to prove the Baire category theorem for complete metric spaces: Let $F=\{F_n:n\in \mathbb N\}$ be a family of dense open subsets and let $V$ be any non-empty open set..... Take $r_n>0$ such that  (i) $B(x_1,r_1)\subset V\cap F_1$ and (ii) $B(x_{n+1},r_n)\subset (V\cap B(x_n,r_n/2))\cap F_{n+1}.$  There exists  $p\in \cap_{n\in \mathbb N}Cl (B(x_n,r_n/2)).$ So for every $n$ we have $p\in V\cap F_n .$ So $V\cap (\cap F)\ne \phi.$ Therefore $\cap F$ is a dense set.